# Question regarding initial guesses for Newton's method in AceGen/ AceFEM

Tags: numerics, finite-element-method, iteration, acegen

I am trying to solve a system of equations with the command `SMTNewtonIteration[]`. This method needs initial guesses for the degrees of freedom I am looking for. Is there a possibility to set the initial guesses by myself and what are the initial guesses set by the programme automatically (are they zero ?)? Moreover, is it possible to output the initial guesses?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The default initial guess is p_0=0 and p_{n+1}_0=p_n. In the manual, you can find options for the SMTNewtonIteration command that can be used to change that.
However, that is not a solution to your problem. Values can become 0 also during the Newton iterations. You have to deal with the problem at the element or formulation level.